# prove that $\|u+v\|^2+\|u-v\|^2=2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Prove that $\|u+v\|^2+\|u-v\|^2=2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2$ using those 4 axioms of inner product. From which axiom should I start?

Comment: Start by listing the 4 axioms of the inner product. Both for those of us reading who don't know what they are, and maybe you'll spot something that might help

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $$\|u+v\|^2+\|u-v\|^2=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle+\langle u-v,u-v\rangle\\=\langle u+v,u\rangle+\langle u+v,v\rangle
+\langle u-v,u\rangle-\langle u-v,v\rangle.$$
where we used the linearity in the second argument.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I get it but still I'm not sure what to do next. Can you help me a little bit more?

Comment: Use the linearity in the first argument, and the  symmetry.